# Study the monotonicity of this function

Tags: functions

The function is $$y=x^2-5x+6$$
I have made
$$[f(x_2)-f(x_1)]/(x_2-x_1)$$
It results in
$$x_1+x_2-5.$$
What should I do next?

Comment: Roll it in paper and light it. What is it you want and why?

Comment: I don't know what level you are at and what tools are available. Maybe you are supposed to use the fact that $y=(x-2)(x-3)$ is an upward facing parabola, with axis of symmetry the vertical line $x=\frac{2+3}{2}$.  Or maybe you are expected to complete the square.  You do not mention calculus, but that too works quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now suppose that $x_2+h =x_1$ with $ h \to 0$. For a positive monotonicity it has to be 
$$\lim_{h \to 0 } x_1+x_1+h -5\geq 0$$

Solving for $x_1$

$x_1 \geq \frac{5}{2}$

Therefore for $x \geq \frac{5}{2}$ the function is positive monotonic. And for $x < \frac{5}{2}$ the function is strictly negative monotonic.

Comment: Please don't use lim, we haven't learnt them yet

Comment: Ok. Do you have any idea what to use instead ? What do your notes say ?